# Irony-parser-like software for other languages than C#?

Tags: parsing, irony

Are there any programs that do what [Irony .NET language implementation kit](https://irony.codeplex.com/) does, but for other programming languages?

Comment: http://www.meta-alternative.net/mbase.html - see http://www.meta-alternative.net/pfdoc.pdf for example. This framework allows to implement embedded DSLs for .NET and to implement any kind of languages targeting .NET, LLVM, C, or whatever else (but you'd still need .NET to run the compiler).

Comment: I think your question is too vague. What are the properties of Irony that you want?

Answer (score 1):

Irony's grammar is encoded in C# with a BNF like notation, but of course you can use it to parse your own or other languages.

If you are looking for a parser/generator that doesn't have its grammar encoded in C#, try something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  With ANTLR, you define your grammar separately in a language description file.

Answer (score 1):

There are *parser combinator libraries* for several other languages, just to name a few:

- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec)
- [Scala](http://debasishg.blogspot.de/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html)
- [Java](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Python has [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), which is a wrapper around Lex/Yacc.

It's quite easy to use once you wrap your head around how they want you to use it and you figure out how to navigate the skimpy documentation. PLY has better documentation than Irony, but the bar is set pretty low.

I started out with PLY, but am finding Irony to be a more enjoyable framework because:

- Irony has support for simple EBNF grammar rules (`MakeStarRule` etc.), whereas accomplishing the same thing in PLY is doable, but cumbersome.
- Both tools have decent out-of-the-box debugging tools, but Irony has a slight edge here because it has a decent GUI for browsing the parsing rules, shift-reduce errors etc.

Good luck to anyone starting out on their Lex/Yacc journey!